# Using the GET array in a GET array?

Tags: php, get, searchbar

I am trying to make a search bar in php with using the get array. This is my html code for the search bar:

```
<form action="index.php?page=searchproc" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="searchq" id="search" placeholder="Search"   maxlength="30"/>

</form>
```

When I enter the form, it goes to the url index.php?searchq=whateveriinputted, but I want it to go to index.php?page=searchproc?searchq=whateveriinputted. I have no idea what I have done wrong but the &page=searchproc just cancels itself.

Thanks,
Raf

Comment: The `action=` GET parameter is discarded. Add an `<input type=hidden>` to preserve it.

Comment: GET is generally a bad idea for forms anyway.

Comment: @e4c5 I don't find anything wrong with `GET` for a search form. It makes it easier for users to share search results. I agree for login forms.

Comment: Search results are one exception to the rule, the very idea that such links can be shared is the reason that GET should not be used.